# Ardunio +HM-10 bluetooth

Tags: c

1. I am using an HM-10 module and Arduino UNO.

   My requirement is to read data from ibeacons near me using Arduino.
   Is it possible?

   How can I detect only 25 beacons?

   Is there any particular range for bluetooth. It will detect only 25 to
   30 beacon? In my project I need to detect more than 100 beacon

Comment: AFAIK, Bluetooth can work with a maximum of 8 devices, given you have only one server.

Comment: IF I ll update bluetooth to V587 also only i ll get 8 devices detected???